# Using feature templates for other layers than original to change target layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, editing, features, arcgis-10.6, template

I was wondering if there is, in ArcMap 10.6, any way to use feature templates in a different layer than the one they where created for. 
I have around 10 layers with similiar atribute tables (same columns) and around 30 different possible types of polygons (landuse like forest, meadow, street...). Every feature that I create gets two attributes: landuse name and landuse ID. I created a feature template for each landuse type in order not having to fill in these atributes manually every time. I would just choose the right landuse template and create the polygon.
However i couldnt find a way to use these templates on any other layer (which has the exact same structure). "Copy" only dublicates the template within the layer. When choosing the template from the first layer in the "create features" dialog, the new feature is also written to that layer...

In other words: is there a way to change the target layer of a feature template?

Comment: Are you using a geodatabase? Look into adding a domain.http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-attribute-domains.htm

Comment: Is there a reason why each type gets its own feature class?

Comment: I checked the domains in a geodatabase, I think that would be a solution. Unfortunately in this project I have some time pressure, so I continued with the existing shapefiles. For now I just merged them all in one layer and will seperate them again later.

Comment: @danak I dont really understand your question. At the moment I have around 30 different possible templates which I use according to the landuse. I have 7 different feature classes because there are 7 different regions. I merged them into on dataset in order to use the same templates all the time.

Comment: It sounded like each type was a different feature.

Comment: You can also fill in data using Field Calculate and selections after you have created it. Though, the domain is a good idea.